# Get object from model based on ForeignKey object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have some problem with getting object from my model. I've something like this:

```
 # Model
 class Subscription(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

 class Subscriber(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

And now I have Subscriber object instance my_user, and I want to get related subscription. So I'm trying something like:

```
 sub = Subscription.objects.get(user=my_user)
```

but I'm getting exception after that. I also' tried:

```
 sub = Subscription.objects.get(user.id=my_user.id)
```

Result still is the same (exception).

Do you have any suggestions or link to documentation, how can I get this object from Subscription collection?

Comment: when you use .get() , if there are multiple objects returned, it throws an exception. Consider using .filter() 

What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Thanks karthir for some hint. I've tried to check in my db, if I really have only one related object, and I found that subscription instance, doesn't have assign any subsscriber.It was my fault.

Comment: never use get without a try catch block, if there are possibility of multiple objects.

Comment: Really, if there is a possibility that the row isn't there in the DB

Comment: Can you post the traceback? It's not clear what your exception is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least based on the models you provided above, I'm not sure why there should be a relation at all.

Subscriber is not related in anyway to Subscription and specifically, the primary IDs of model probably shouldn't be related (user.id=my_user.id), unless you are designing it explicitly like that.

Moreover, this:

```
sub = Subscription.objects.get(user=my_user)
```

will only work if there if there is some sort of relation that django knows about.

In my view you should do something like this:

```
 class Subscription(models.Model):
    subscriber= models.ForeignKey('Subscriber')
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=10)


 class Subscriber(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5) #PS, if you ever save anything longer than 5 char's this will raise an exception.
```

This will allow you to make queries like:

```
my_user = Subscriber.obejects.get(something=someotherthing)
sub = Subscription.objects.get(subscriber=my_user)
```

Comment: You are right James. In my model should be placed Subscriber where I wrote User. At this moment everything works ok.